# RedirectToAction does not redirect me to action when triggered by jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this code - it is supposed to delete project from database.

It works fine - the project gets deleted and a message pops out, but in last line of delete method there is this line of code

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))
```

yet after deleting the project, it stays on the `Edit` view (where delete partial view is located).

Controller

```
[Route("projects")]
[Authorize]
public class ProjectManagerController : Controller

//Fields...

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var projects = await _mediator.Send(new GetProjectsQuery());
        return View(projects);
    }

//Other methods...

    [HttpDelete("delete")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromQuery]string encodedName)
    {
        var command = new DeleteProjectCommand() { EncodedName = encodedName};
        await _mediator.Send(command);
        this.SetNotification("success", $"Project has been deleted");

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); //hit by breakpoint but does not redirect 
    }
```

jQuery Edit.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#editProject form").submit(function (event) {
        return true;
    });

    $('#deleteButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const encodedName = $(this).data('encodedname'); // Get encodedName inside the click handler
        $.ajax({
            url: `/projects/delete?encodedName=${encodeURIComponent(encodedName)}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            async: false, // Set the request to be synchronous
            success: function (data) {
                toastr["success"]("Deleted project");
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr["error"]("Something went wrong");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I used couple breakpoints - `RedirectToAction` method is hit, `encodedName` is passed, ajax works to so I don't know what is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used couple breakpoints - RedirectToAction method is hit,
> encodedName is passed, ajax works to so I don't know what is it

Well, as you are submiting ajax request which always expect a response and execute either of success or error. So this return statement `RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))` would be executed however, as its a ajax request so always ended up with either `success` or `error` block and cannot redirected to Index action from backend and for ajax request its by design, you cannot stop respose or modify the redirection from backend because, request always get back to ajax either success or error block. You have to do that (redirection) within success or error block.

Let's have a look in practice how to can achieve that.

In order to redirect to your index action, you should write redirect mechanism within your ajax success function block.

```
<button type="button" name="submitButton" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
        id="deleteButton">
    Submit Request
</button>



@section scripts {
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#deleteButton').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
               // const encodedName = $(this).data('encodedname'); 
                const encodedName = "TestName"; // Get encodedName inside the click handler
                $.ajax({
                    url: `https://localhost:7230/projects/delete?encodedName=${encodeURIComponent(encodedName)}`,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    async: false, // Set the request to be synchronous
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Deleted project");
                        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "ProjectManager")"
                        // toastr["success"]("Deleted project");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        // toastr["error"]("Something went wrong");
                        alert("Something went wrong");
                        console.log("Something went wrong")
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** As you can see upon your success response from your delete controller, `window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "ProjectManager")"`  will redirect to your desired action.

Modify controller return type:

Within your delete controller action instead of `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))` you should re-write return type as success or error response code in order to decided which block need to execute in ajax call.

```
        [HttpDelete("delete")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromQuery] string encodedName)
        {
            //var command = new DeleteProjectCommand() { EncodedName = encodedName };
            //await _mediator.Send(command);
            //this.SetNotification("success", $"Project has been deleted");

            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); //hit by breakpoint but does not redirect 
            if (encodedName == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

**Note:** This is actually proof of concept logic, you should modify it as per your requirement.

Output:

[image]